# Extract some items from a list to build a new list

Tags: python, regex

I have got some lists, and I want to filter elements from them. Here's the lists:

```
list1 = ['Little Mary had a lamb', 'the horse is black', 'Mary had a cat']
list2 = ['The horse is white', 'Mary had a dog', 'The horse is hungry']
listn = ...
```

Assume that I know a word or an expression which is relevant, *Mary* or *horse* in the following example. I would like to get a new list which items would be extracted from the other lists if these items contain the term or the expression searched.
E.g. :

```
listMary = ['Little Mary had a lamb', 'Mary had a cat', 'Mary had a dog'] 
listHorse = ['the horse is black', 'The horse is white', 'The horse is hungry']
listn = ...
```

Don't worry my data is more complex ;)

I know that i should use the regular expression module, but I am unable to find in which way in this case. I have tried a few searches here on Stack Overflow but I don't know how to formulate the problem clearly enough so I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be something like:

```
>>> a = ['Little Mary had a lamb', 'the horse is black', 'Mary had a cat']
>>> b = ['The horse is white', 'Mary had a dog', 'The horse is hungry']
>>> [sent for sent in a+b if 'Mary' in sent]
['Little Mary had a lamb', 'Mary had a cat', 'Mary had a dog']
```

Or if you prefer using a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> [sent for sent in a+b if re.search("horse", sent)]
['the horse is black', 'The horse is white', 'The horse is hungry']
```

Comment: Thanks everybody _ For regex i don't know : some people said me that it was a bad idea ut until your answer i did not know how to manage my question without this module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional clause of a list comprehension.

```
[x for x in L if regex.search(x)]
```

Comment: Or, to account for multiple lists: `sum([[x for x in L if regex.search(x)] for L in (L1,L2,L3)],[])`

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the regex module:

```
word = 'horse'
result = []
for l in [list1, list2, list3]:
    for sentence in l:
        if word in sentence:
            result.append(sentence)
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` would be better here http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: @gnibbler: Thanks, I didn't know about that function yet.

Answer (score 0):

User inbuilt function `filter`  it will be fast and efficient.

```
def f(x): 
    return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0

filter(f, range(2, 25))
```

so here def f will take one arg and make your match and return true false and you will have your result list.

Thank You